# Formula for a simple connecting homomorphism of inclusion

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homological-algebra

We work in Singular homology. This exact sequence can be found in pg97 of Intro. Alg. Top. by Rotman.

Let $A \subseteq X$ be subspace of space $X$. In category of topological pairs, the inclusions
then induces SES
$$0 \rightarrow S_*(A, \emptyset) \rightarrow S_*(X, \emptyset) \rightarrow S_*(X)/S_*(A)\rightarrow 0$$
By diagram chasing in homological algebra, there is a LES, where $H_n(A,\emptyset)=H_n(A)$,
$$\cdots \rightarrow H_n(A) \rightarrow H_n(X) \rightarrow H_n(X,A) \xrightarrow{d} H_{n-1}(A)\rightarrow \cdots $$

My question is , what exactly does the map $d$ do? It seems weird and so simple:

> 1. Take a cycle in $S_n(X)/S_n(A)$, which must be of form $[\sum m_i \tau_i ]$. Pull back to $S_n(X)$, $\sum m_i \tau_i$, of which choice of representative is relevant, and $\tau_i$ are the basis maps $\Delta^n \rightarrow X$.
> 2. Push to $S_{n-1}(X)$, $\partial \sum m_i \tau_i = \sum m_i \partial \tau_i$. But by diagram chase, this is can be seen as an element of $S_{n-1}(A)$.
> 3. So we have that $$d:[\sum m_i \tau_i ] \mapsto [ \sum m_i \partial \tau_i ] $$

Am I doing this right?

Comment: That sounds correct. It’s simple once you get the idea behind it! Not sure what part is weird but maybe it becomes less weird the more you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of $S_n(X)/S_n(A)$ as the free Abelian group on the
singular $n$-simplices in $X$ which do not lie in $A$. If one does that,
the boundary of a cycle $\alpha$ in $S_n(X)/S_n(A)$ is a chain
$\partial\alpha\in S_{n-1}(A)$, since those are the chains that
become zero in $S_{n-1}(X)/S_{n-1}(A)$. Then $\partial\alpha$ is a cycle
in $A$ (obviously $\partial(\partial\alpha))=0$),
so induces an element of $H_{n-1}(A)$. The map $\alpha\mapsto\partial\alpha$ therefore induces a map $d:H_n(X,A)\to H_{n-1}(A)$.